# read(0, &c,1); -- read читает данные из stdout и stdin

Tags: c

```
fprintf (stdout,"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
while(1)
read(0, &c,1);
```

В терминал должна вывестись строка, но он остается пустым, значит read читает ее.

Почему `read` читает данные из стандартного потока вывода и ввода, когда я явно указал ему читать данные только из stdin?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что "read читает данные из стандартного потока вывода и ввода"???

Comment: @AnT, ой, в вопросе не написал, сейчас дополню

Comment: Попробуйте читать документацию, её не просто так пишут, наверное.

Comment: @0andriy, чуть что, так сразу документация, где бы я нашел ответ в документации? Я же думал что во всем виновата read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В терминал должна вывестись строка, но он остается пустым, значит read читает ее.

Стандартный терминал буферизуется построчно. В него ничего не "должно" выводиться, пока выводимая строка не завершится символом перевода строки. Вы свою строку не завершили символом перевода строки - вот она и не выводится, а тихо сидит в строчном буфере.

С чего вы вдруг взяли, что "значит read читает ее" - ума не приложу. Это прям как логика из анекдота "Коробка квадратная, значит внутри что-то круглое."

Comment: Так если убрать `read` то строка выведется

Comment: @Николай Николаевич: Разумеется она когда-нибудь рано или поздно выведется: либо вы наконец выведете символ `\n`, либо ваша программа завершится и накопленный буфер вывода будет вытолкнут на вывод. Но в любом случае к `read` все это никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Николай Николаевич: Можете сделать `fflush(stdout)` чтобы насильно вытолкнуть эту строку из строчного буфера на вывод, не дожидаясь символа `\n`.

Comment: А почему тогда если я введу: printf("введите что-нибудь"); scanf("%s",stroka); то перед scanf выведется строка "введите что-нибудь"?

Comment: @Николай Николаевич: Это не гарантируется впрямую спецификацией языка, хотя стандарт языка *рекомендует* автоматическое выталкивание `stdout` перед чтением `stdin`. Формально говоря вам просто повезло, что ваша библиотека это делает, но в общем случае на это рассчитывать нельзя. В общем случае в такой ситуации вы должны сделать `fflush` сами.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо))